# Derivative of Hadamard Product Multiply by Summing Vector (each element is 1)

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

Given $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, diagonal matrix $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$,
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{W}(\mathbf{AX} \odot \mathbf{AX}) \mathbf{1}_{3}
$$

where $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 3}$, $\mathbf{1}_{3}\in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$ is a vector with all the elements equal to 1, $\odot$ is Hadamard product (elements-wise product).

How to compute $\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$? Sorry for my poor tensor understanding, matrix form would be better.

Many thanks!

Comment: In your self-answer, you need to replace $\def\p{\partial}\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}} \D(2AX)$ with $\D(\v(2AX))$. This gives you $\frac{\p f}{\p\,\v(X)}$ but not $\frac{\p f}{\p X}$ as you claim.
You could also employ the single entry matrix $E_{ij}$ and component-wise derivatives to obtain $\frac{\p f}{\p X_{ij}}=2W(AX\odot AE_{ij}){\tt1}\;$

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it.

$$
\begin{aligned}
d \mathbf{F} &= d\left[\mathbf{W\left(AX \odot AX\right)\mathbf{1}_{3}} \right] \\
&= d \mathbf{W} \left[\left(\mathbf{AX \odot AX}\right)\mathbf{1}_{3}\right] + \mathbf{W} d \left[\left(\mathbf{AX \odot AX}\right)\mathbf{1}_{3}\right] \\
&= \mathbf{W} d \left[\left(\mathbf{AX \odot AX}\right)\mathbf{1}_{3}\right] \\
&= \mathbf{W} d \left(\mathbf{AX \odot AX}\right) \mathbf{1}_{3} + \mathbf{W} \left(\mathbf{AX \odot AX}\right) d \mathbf{1}_{3} \\
&= \mathbf{W} d \left(\mathbf{AX \odot AX}\right) \mathbf{1}_{3} \\
&= \mathbf{W} \left[2\mathbf{\left(AX\right)} \odot d \left(\mathbf{AX}\right)\right] \mathbf{1}_{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
vec\left(d\mathbf{F}\right) &= vec \left(\mathbf{W} \left[2\mathbf{\left(AX\right)} \odot d \left(\mathbf{AX}\right)\right] \mathbf{1}_{3}\right) \\
&= \left(\mathbf{1}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{W}\right) vec\left[2\mathbf{\left(AX\right)} \odot d \left(\mathbf{AX}\right)\right] \\
&= \left(\mathbf{1}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{W}\right) \left [vec \left(2\mathbf{AX}\right) \odot vec \left(\mathbf{A} d \mathbf{X}\right) \right] \\
&= \left(\mathbf{1}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{W}\right) diag\left(2 \mathbf{vec \left(AX\right)}\right) vec \left(\mathbf{A} d \mathbf{X}\right) \\
&= \left(\mathbf{1}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{W}\right) diag\left(2 \mathbf{vec \left(AX\right)}\right) vec \left(\mathbf{A} \left(d \mathbf{X}\right) \mathbf{I}_{3} \right) \\
&= \left(\mathbf{1}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{W}\right) diag\left(2 \mathbf{vec \left(AX\right)}\right) \left(\mathbf{I}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{A}\right) vec \left(d \mathbf{X}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\therefore \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \left[\left(\mathbf{1}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{W}\right) diag\left(2 \mathbf{vec \left(AX\right)}\right) \left(\mathbf{I}_{3}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{A}\right)\right] ^{T}
$$

Is that right? Feel free to let me know if I made any mistake.

Comment: Since $F$ is a vector $\,{\rm vec}(F)=F,\,$ and the same is true for ${\rm vec}(dF).\;$ However your final conclusion is not valid. The quantity $\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\right)$ is a third-order tensor of size $(k\times n\times 3)$, and cannot be written using standard matrix notation. However, most computer languages will allow you to `reshape()` the elements of the matrix-valued gradient $\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial {\rm vec}(X)}\right)$ into a tensor.

Comment: @greg, thanks for the kindly reply! You are right that $\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$ is a third-order tensor strictly speaking. Because I haven't learned tensor systematically and I am not good at it，sometimes higher order tensors can be represented using Kronecker products. So I always try to reshape tensor to a matrix form, e.g. $\frac{\partial \mathbf{A X}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{I}_{n} \otimes \mathbf{A}^{T}$, something like that. Look at it this way, do I get a right result is my self-answer above?